# How to force a order for calling React.js hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

Is it possible to enforce a specific order in which React hooks are used? For example some linting/prettier settings that will always make sure to first use 'useState' hooks and only after that use 'useEffect' hooks. Let's say I have the following code:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [myState1, setMyState1] = React.useState();
    const [myState2, setMyState2] = React.useState();

    React.useEffect(() => {
        runSomeEffect()
    }, [])

    const [myState3, setMyState3] = React.useState();

    return <div>...</div>
}
```

I would like to have some sort of warning that the third `useState` hooks should be moved to the top. I looked into Eslint and Prettier, but I don't think any of those have rules to enforce the order of React hooks.

Comment: You can't use useState but you can use other hooks to replace the useState functionality.
EG, UseContext, UseReducer (Redux) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have such rule as the call order of hooks matters due to [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper).

> By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple useState and useEffect calls.

You have an in-depth explanation of why, [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation).

> React relies on the order in which Hooks are called

Therefore such a rule may cause unexpected behavior where the developer would enforce order and the rule will break it.

Comment: But why would this matter if I always have my React hooks in the same order? I understand that when conditionally rendering hooks, the order might change and this could cause bugs. But if I create a rule where the `useState` should always be declared before `useEffect`, the order of the hooks will never change and should still function correctly.

Comment: In common cases, it does not matter, but for edge cases usually when there are dependencies between a few useStates and useEffect the order can cause a bug. You can't apply a rule on an assumption "should still function correctly"

Comment: Okey that makes sense. Thanks!